# Where does the type erasure happen and what is a safe way to stay away from this?

Tags: scala, type-conversion, scala-2.10

```
def decode(l: List[(Int, Symbol)]) : List[Symbol] = {
    def foo(r : Int, s: Symbol):List[Symbol] = r match {
      case 0 => Nil
      case x: Int => s::foo(r-1,s)
    }

    l match {
      case Nil => Nil
      case h::tail => foo(h._1 , h._2 ) :+ decode(tail)
    }

}
```

Here I get a compilation error "scala: type mismatch; found:List[Object] required: List[Symbol] case h::tail => foo(h._1 : Int, h._2 : Symbol) :+ decode(tail)
                                                     "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a type erasure, simple type mismatch:

```
foo(h._1 , h._2 ) :+ decode(tail)
```

Result of foo is `List[Symbol]`, result of decode is `List[Symbol]`. Now you're trying to put `List` inside `List`, no surprize that compiler thinks that the only way to store `List` and `Symbols` inside `List` is to give that later list Object (Any) type.

Most likely you wanted to simply combine two lists:

```
foo(h._1 , h._2 ) ++ decode(tail)
```